# CSS Border radius, border color ghost corner borders in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

Morning,

I have the following code that works in all browsers other than IE. I want a blue border to appear when clicking on input boxes, however did not want to see the elements resizing and positioning. I fixed this by putting a border colour to match the background colour, thus removing the resizing effect. However, on IE, you get ghost borders which seem to be a combination of both the border radius and border colour (background colour). Any ideas of how to fix this without using box shadow?

Screen Shot showing ghost borders:

[image]

```html
input,
textarea,
select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #4f4f4f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 6px auto 22px auto;
  width: 260px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid #4cc7fa;
  }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I tried adding a property `background-clip: padding-box` however this only works to a point, as then you focus on the box, you then get a ghost inner shadow to the box. Weird.

Comment: Have you tried to add `box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box;` ?

Comment: yes, im afraid that doesnt work :-( cheers though

Comment: Second option: replace `border: 3px solid #4cc7fa` with `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #4cc7fa`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to overcome the ghost/resize/re-positioning effect, where you change `border-width` on focus and compensate its re-positioning with a negative `top`

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 6px auto 22px auto;
  width: 260px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

input:focus {
  top: -3px;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #4cc7fa;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would use the following *javascript*:

```
Your-function() {
document.getElementsByTagName('input','textarea','select').classlist.toggle('show')
}
```

2. add `display:none` to `input:focus`
3. add the following *css*

```
.show
{
display:block;
}
```

**Note**: Add `onclick="Yourfunction()"` to your markup to load the js.

Comment: This does not fix the ghost border in IE, which is the problem